# Xdebug not working with PHPStorm

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm, centos6

I use PHPStorm along with Xdebug to step through my code.  PHPStorm is running on a Windows 7 machine, and my local webserver is running on a separate CentOS 6.4 machine.  I've done a `phpinfo();` to verify that Xdebug is being loaded by PHP, and it is.  The following are the settings for my Xdebug in the PHP.ini:

```
    [xdebug]
    zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so"
    xdebug.remote_enable = 1
    xdebug.remote_port = 9000
    xdebug.remote_host = "192.168.1.130"
    xdebug.remote_log = "/var/log/httpd/xdebug_log"
```

I similarly setup PHPStorm to use my CentOS server as the debugging server, and I listen for connections.  I assigned static IPs to both of these machines.  Using a Chrome Xdebug plugin to set the appropriate cookies, I attempt to set a breakpoint, but nothing happens.  When I go to look in /var/log/httpd/xdebug_log (which has 777 permissions), nothing is written there.  I've opened up port 9000, and I can telnet from my CentOS machine back to my Windows machine on port 9000 no problem.  I also set SELinux to permissive, but to no avail.

Any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: Well ... if you have NOTHING in xdebug_log file ... then xdebug simply not getting debug request (cookie/get/post parameter etc). You can FORCE debug mode: `xdebug_break();` to programmaticaly hit breakpoint or with `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` or `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` (check docs for details). SELinux definitely can cause issues (not expert at all in this regard). In any case, have a look at this as well: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but still no luck.  when I call `xdebug_var_dump()` or `xdebug_is_enabled()`, I'm getting values indicating that xdebug is working.  However, PHPStorm is not connecting.  I've quadruple checked my remote server settings, and I can 100% tell you that they are correct.

Comment: I'm shaking my head at myself... I rebooted CentOS, and all is working now.  Ugh, I really need to start following my own advice and try a reboot before wasting your guys' time ;-)

Comment: This is not a waste of time, this is a valid solution to your problem and an important reminder to always 'check the plug'.

Answer (score 15):

Try to configure your project in PhpStorm

1. Open Settings->Languages & Frameworks->PHP->Debug
2. Uncheck the "Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations" option
3. OK

Comment: could you please add a "why this works" to this answer?

Comment: Checkbox "Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations" means that domain name of your local website (you trying to debug) must be listed in the PHP -> Servers (in phpstrom config). If no, then your website will be ignored by phpstorm.

Comment: Thank you, I was testing xdebug with a random file not present inside the project  andit was working for me with the browser addon, but then I went ahead and created my own debug server in config, for the file I was testing and then it seems PHPStorm might have automatically enabled the option to ignore external connections...

I disabled it and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 4):

Add to your php.ini:

`xdebug.mode=debug`

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue, below are the steps I performed to resolve it:

1. Make sure you have xdebug installed and in php.ini uncomment `xdebug.mode=debug`
2. Open Settings->Languages & Frameworks->PHP->Debug, Assign Debug Port value, you can find this port from php.ini. In my case, it was 9002
3. Now Validate debugger configurations - here you need to add the path to your web application files and URL. Click validate.
4. Now Start Listening -> Enable listening for PHP Debug Connection.

After this setup you can set a break point and start debugging with XDEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i added folder that im debugging to exclusive, so it return 502 or blank page when i put breakpoint. Remove exclusive folder and everything working.

You can consider this blog to find more solution: [Link](https://5minuteshack.blogspot.com/2022/08/xdebug-phpstorm-and-docker-why-it-not.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo gedit /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini

zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9898
xdebug.idekey = “PHPSTORM”
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9898
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.