# Can't get debugging work on PhpStorm 2016.2.1 with Xdebug

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I have installed PhpStorm 2016.2.1 (EAP) and everything should be working fine but sadly debugging is not working for me. I have tried zero-configuration from [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) without success :(

**Useful information:**

- I have a VM running CentOS 7 where I have the LAMP environment.
- The `/var/www/html/plataforma56.local` is the path on the server where the project is
- The remote path is mapped through SFTP to my host (using SFTP Net)
- The project under PhpStorm is type of: "Source files are in a local directory, no Web server is yet configured".
- PHP version is 5.6.24
- Xdebug version is 2.4.1
- Xdebug is enabled (see pic below)

[image]

- I have check Xdebug using the HTML generated by `phpinfo()` and the [Xdebug wizard page](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) and everything is fine as per the output:

  ```
  Summary

  Xdebug installed: 2.4.1
  Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
  Windows: no
  Zend Server: no
  PHP Version: 5.6.24
  Zend API nr: 220131226
  PHP API nr: 20131226
  Debug Build: no
  Thread Safe Build: no
  Configuration File Path: /etc
  Configuration File: /etc/php.ini
  Extensions directory: /usr/lib64/php/modules
  ```
- I am running Windows 10 x64
- My AV is ESET Smart Security (and yes I have disable the Firewall just for see if this is the root cause but without success)
- IP/Port in Xdebug configuration is fine I've checked several times (even [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) under Communication Setup is a very useful animation explaining what happen so we can understand properly)
- There is not application running on Windows using port `9005`
- phpStorm is installed in a host with IP: `192.168.3.1`
- IDE is configured

[image]

[image]

- Path mapping is configured

[image]

- SFTP connection is just working

[image]

- Xdebug is enabled in the browser (Chrome/Firefox both running latest version) using Xdebug Helper extension ...
- In Cookies ...

[image]

- In Session Storage (set manually by me just in case)

[image]

- In Local Storage (set manually by me just in case)

[image]

- Finally the little icon green said: Extension is enabled

[image]

- Breakpoints are set and multiple times and I have also added a programmatic break point: `xdebug_break()`

[image]

- I have check also if port if open in the host and listening and here is the result:

  ```
  ==================================================
  Process Name      : PhpStorm64.exe
  Process ID        : 7496
  Protocol          : TCP
  Local Port        : 9005
  Local Port Name   : 
  Local Address     : 0.0.0.0
  Remote Port       : 
  Remote Port Name  : 
  Remote Address    : 0.0.0.0
  Remote Host Name  : 
  State             : Listening
  Process Path      : C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2016.2.1\bin\PhpStorm64.exe
  Product Name      : PhpStor
  File Description  : PhpStor
  File Version      : 2016.2.1.PS-162.1447.
  Company           : JetBrains s.r.o.
  Process Created On: 8/6/2016 12:53:41 PM
  User Name         : REYNIERDESKTOP\ReynierPM
  Process Services  : 
  Process Attributes: A
  Added On          : 8/6/2016 1:54:39 PM
  Module Filename   : 
  Remote IP Country : 
  ==================================================
  ```

Finally, this is the configuration block at `/etc/php.ini`:

```
[Xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable    = true (I have play with true|1 here)
xdebug.remote_host      = 192.168.3.1
xdebug.remote_port      = 9005
xdebug.idekey           = XDEBUG_PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_handler   = dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable  = 0
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_log       = "/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

Having all this information I should ask:

- I am missing something here?
- Why this is not working?
- Since this is a CodeIgniter 3 project it would be possible to debug this application? (dummy question but maybe is not possible for some reason)

The only thing I am missing here is Xdebug logs but I am not seeing any file under `/tmp/xdebug.log` on the server (maybe is not setup properly on my configuration, you tell me)

I am open to any solution because I am run out of ideas at this point and have spent hours trying to get this working (is the best when you're running into application issues that you need to fix)

**Note:** I know this is a common and recurrent issue and have been asked several times but before close it, or mark as duplicate or down vote please try to help.

I should add here that I've read this list of posts:

- [Xdebug not working with PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937417/xdebug-not-working-with-phpstorm?rq=1)
- [How to setup PHPStorm debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608501/how-to-setup-phpstorm-debugger?rq=1)
- [PHPStorm + XDebug Setup Walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183179/phpstorm-xdebug-setup-walkthrough)
- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/03/configure-php-debugging-in-phpstorm-2-0/
- [xdebug running in PHPStorm unable to connect to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039055/xdebug-running-in-phpstorm-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server?rq=1)
- [Debug Symfony2 with XDebug and PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797361/debug-symfony2-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm?rq=1)
- [XDebug with Symfony and PhpStorm doesn't work (Ubuntu installation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111467/xdebug-with-symfony-and-phpstorm-doesnt-work-ubuntu-installation?rq=1)

And I could keep adding more and more since I have spent hours trying to find why isn't working.

**EDIT: Run/Debug configuration screen**

[image]

Comment: You need to provide xdebug logs. There is no way (for me at least) to tell if xdebug is even listening there without such logs. The log should tell to what IP/port it tries to connect and what file it wants to debug. You may also try older xdebug version (2.4.0 or even 2.3.x) -- maybe it's something wrong with this xdebug build etc.

Comment: @LazyOne can you help me to get such logs? I am not seeing them anywhere, that's what I said here "The only thing I am missing here is Xdebug logs but I am not seeing any file under /tmp/xdebug.log on the server (maybe is not setup properly on my configuration, you tell me)"

Comment: Limited access rights? Try different folder where Apache/PHP can write for sure. Try with `remote_autostart = 1` so that xdebug would try to edit every single script. I have no idea why xdebug would not be able to write to the log while it still can debug. I've seen only one question here where person said: "ok, it's working now .. but still no logs" .. but in ALL other cases that I remember logs were generated...

Comment: @LazyOne isn't working, I have change the path to where Apache writes logs and no `/var/log/httpd/xdebug.log` file is being created, also I have added the line you told me

Comment: Not a Linux person -- do not know what it could be (why logs are not generated). My only suggestion under such circumstances -- try different xdebug version/build.

Comment: @LazyOne already tried that, I have two different VM: one running CentOS 7 with PHP 5.6.24 and Xdebug 2.4.1 and a second one running CentOS 6.8 with PHP 7.0.4 and Xdebug 2.4.0 in none of them debugging works, would you like to try some remote assistance?

Comment: Well .. I can have a look using TeamViewer .. but without xdebug logs it most likely would not be productive. Send me TV login details (make a chat or something)

Comment: @LazyOne let me know when you've a time and we can do a TeamViewer

Comment: What says the phpstorm debug validation tool? (Run -> Web Server Debug Validation)

Comment: @user3528269 it says "Please, configure remote path mapping for the validation directory" but .. what else I should configure?

Comment: Ah you're running inside a vm. Did you setup the 'PHP Remote Debug' Configuration? And if yes, how does it look like? And you want to debug from outside of the VM I guess?

Comment: @user3528269, yes I am running inside a VM, and yes I've that setup take a look to the edit on the OP

Comment: @ReynierPM In that VM that does not work -- what Linux-wide "protection" tool is used? SELinux? If so -- see if `setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1, nttpd restart` will help (took it from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206357399-Remote-debug-in-phpstorm-with-xdebug)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running on vagrant+php7.0.10+xdebug2.4.1. I set the `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` option in `php.ini` and that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have installed successfull with php7.0.9 xdebug 2.4.0 custom port . I used FPM-FastCgi too. phpv5.6 still can't make it work with phpstorm and xdebug

Comment: Is  this remote or local debug?

Comment: I have fixed it

Comment: @mrtuvn would you mind detailing how you fixed it? i have the same problem!

Answer (score -1):

Same problem. I work on vagrant VM machine and php56 + xdebug 2.4.1.
Remote debug does not work!

Comment: Did you get this fixed?